# AJAX Returning ParseError

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am facing trouble with ajax while sending my data. Ajax returns ParseError I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function redeem_all_pts(co_id) {
    var path = base_url+"cmaster/redeem_all"; 

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:path,
        data:'co_id='+co_id,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log("success!!="+resp);
        },
        error:function(resp, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }   
    }); 
}
```

where as my PHP function is

```php
public function redeem_all() {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    if (!empty($user_id)) {
        $co_id = $this->input->post('co_id');
        $this->db->set('co_ytd_points','0', false);
        $this->db->where('co_id' , $co_id);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('pages/login');
    }  
}
```

Exact Error when I debugged the code on google chrome is:

> resp = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200,
>   statusText: "OK"}, error = "parsererror"

Comment: ParseError *what, where?*

Comment: Include the whole error you get please.

Comment: So the data received is not a valid json...do you have notices or smth?

Comment: Please attach the logs

Comment: Hi Everyone I have updated the question.

Comment: I think you are loading html content but your ajax expects json data type from a quick glance

Comment: Also post the JSON response you get when you hit the API

Comment: You are using `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax so if the output is not json it will give the ParseError. If you replace it with `dataType: 'html'` it will give you the result and then you can figure out where you get wrong

Comment: @BilalAmjad put var_dump($user_id) and $co_id then you can identify the error

Answer (score 1):

Still have error because value return from PHP file is not in JSON format 
**Add this after PHP open tag**

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

**Make sure data echo in JSON format by using**

```
echo json_encode($yourVarible);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this part is making problems:

```
data:'co_id='+co_id,
```

It should be something like:

```
data: {'co_id': co_id}
```

Comment: Do You need to send data in JSON format or standard POST data format?

Comment: We need to get data through JSON

Comment: is it possible that co_id variable is undefined or empty?

Comment: I have tried by adding hard coded value as data:{"co_id" : 1} but still error persists

Comment: I have a feeling that this is response parse error, not the request

Answer (score 0):

Simply post data with json object like

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:path,
        data:{"co_id" : co_id},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(resp)
        {
            console.log("success!!="+resp);
        },
        error:function(resp, error){
            console.log(error);
        }   
    });
```